# How to pass authentication to WCF service

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wcf-authentication

I have web site configured in IIS. The `default web site` is the main web site and there is `MVC application` and `WCF application` configured under the `default web site`. Something like below

[image]

The `default web site` is using OpenID connect authentication using cookie authentication. So when user try to access any resource from `default web site` or its child applications he gets redirected to login page.  This is working fine as expected.

Now i have requirement where `MVC` application needs to invoke an operation from `WCF` service on a button click. So i added a service reference into MVC application and configured binding as below

**WCF Service Configuration**

```
    <system.serviceModel>
        <extensions>
          <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="silverlightFaults" type="Framework.Wcf.SilverlightFaultBehavior, Framework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b297de4b0f792ff8" />
          </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>
        <services>
          <service name="DocumentManagementService.DocumentManagementService" behaviorConfiguration="DocumentManagementServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint name="BasicHttpEndPoint" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="DocumentManagementService.Contracts.IDocumentManagement" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndPoint" behaviorConfiguration="SilverlightFaultBehavior" />        
          </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpEndPoint" closeTimeout="00:2:00" openTimeout="00:2:00" receiveTimeout="0:5:00" sendTimeout="00:5:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="104857600" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="104857600" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DocumentManagementServiceBehavior">          
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>          
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="SilverlightFaultBehavior">
              <silverlightFaults />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
     </system.serviceModel>
```

**MVC Configuration ( this is client)**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
       <basicHttpBinding>        
          <binding name="BasicHttpEndPoint" closeTimeout="00:2:00" openTimeout="00:2:00" receiveTimeout="0:5:00" sendTimeout="00:5:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="104857600" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="104857600" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
        </binding> 
      </basicHttpBinding>     
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://XXXXX/DocumentManagementService/DocumentManagementService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndPoint"
        contract="DMProxy.IDocumentManagement" name="BasicHttpEndPoint" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

However when i invoke the WCF Operation i get error

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   ''.

Note that when user clicks on a button, at that time he is already been authenticated. I am not sure how that authentication will get passed to WCF application.

**Update 1**

IIS  Authetication for Default Web Site

[image]

IIS  Authetication for WCF

[image]

**Update 2**
I think* i need to add authentication cookie in Cookies and HttpHeader before i make WCF call. ?? Any idea how would i do that

Comment: What authenication do you have selected in IIS for your WCF app?

Comment: @Popo See update 1